502 Bad Gateway when going on /phpmyadmin
I've configured my server with nginx, php 8.3, mysql, phpmyadmin
And when I go to www.my_domain.fr/phpmyadmin
I get this error : 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.24.0 (Ubuntu)
Iv'e tried a lot of topic mentionning all sort of thing but nothing seem to work

PHP-FPM is Running?

Hi, I'm pretty new to the thing so how do you do that

execute: sudo systemctl status php8.3-fpm

I get that in return - Unit php8.3-fpm.service could not be found.

it means that PHP-FPM for PHP 8.3 is not installed or not properly set up on your server. To resolve this issue, you'll need to install PHP-FPM for PHP 8.3 and ensure that it is configured correctly.

Do you have any recommendation or ressource so I can do so ?

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04 please check this one if you are using ubuntu, this has whole setup for your stack setup just the version of php is low which you can modify

https://php.watch/articles/php-8.3-install-upgrade-on-debian-ubuntu

Okay now when I run - sudo systemctl status php8.3-fpm It give me an answer that is good but I still have the 502 bad gateway

What control panel are you using? cPanel? And what does sudo systemctl status php8.3-fpm return after you have installed php 8.3 (fpm)?
